Blog with Dynamic Routing via Content Collections in Astro (SSG Mode)
I'm having trouble with dynamic routing in Astro. I'm working with a Content Collection called "Articles" and then created a route: [slug].astro. However, the slug does not resolve to the markdown content, and every time I've run my dev server it resolves to a 404 page, despite my code editor validating that the data has been imported from my Collection folder into the "pages" subdirectory.
From my content/config.ts file:
const articles = defineCollection ({
  type: "content",
  schema: ( {image} ) => z.object({
    title: z.string(),
    category: reference("sections"),
    cover: image(),
    coverAlt: z.string().optional(),
    description: z.string(),
    date: z.date(),
    identifier: z.number(),
    seaslug: z.string().optional(),
  })
})



export const collections = {
  articles,
}

From my articles/[slug].astro file:
---
import { getEntry, getCollection } from "astro:content";

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const articles = await getCollection('articles');
  return articles.map((p) => ({
    params: { slug: p.slug },
  }));
}

const { slug } = Astro.params;

const articles = await getEntry("articles", slug)

const { Content } = await articles.render();

---

<h1>{articles.data.title}</h1>
<Content />


seems you're missing a loader in the defineCollection call? See https://docs.astro.build/en/tutorial/6-islands/4/#create-a-collection-for-your-posts
